# Logstash: "type" : "index_not_found_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

I am following the [Logstash tutorial20](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html).

This command  returns the following error:

[image]

The following is my configure:
[image]

[image]

I have two questions：
What is the right get? Who can give me a correct statement？
Why can I see an index  was created from the Plgin Head after I run the XGET? --I have never used XPUT.

Comment: your index is named apachelogs-2015.01.07, but you are searching "logstash-2015.01.07" index, which does not exist

Comment: After I run  "XGET localhost:9200/logstash-2015.01.07", a  index  named apachelogs-2015.01.07 is created.
I do not know why.